# Processing multiple files and write a csv file for each

Tags: python, csv, pickle

I wrote a code that works fine for single file, but I have to change the names for each file. It reads a pickle file, write it into a txt file, then does some process on the context of txt file and produce a list of numbers, at the end stores the list in a dataframe and write that dataframe in csv file.

```
def get_value_of_list(bit_list):
p_number = 0
for i in bit_list:
    if i == 1:
        p_number = p_number + 1
return p_number

def cross_entropy(p, q):
    return -sum([p[i] * log2(q[i]) for i in range(len(p))])

if __name__ == "__main__":

file_name = 'pickleData_AIMchat2.txt'
pickle_file = 'AIMchat2.pickle'
pk = PickleToFile(file_name, pickle_file)
pk.create_pickle_file()
h = HexToBinary(file_name)
hex_list = h.read_file()
num_of_bits = 8

scale = 16
bin_data = []
for i in hex_list:
    bin_data.append(bin(int(i, scale))[2:].zfill(num_of_bits))

my_bit_list = []
for byte in bin_data:
    bit_list = []
    for bit in byte:
        bit_list.append(int(bit))
    num_of_one_divided_by_eight = get_value_of_list(bit_list) / 8
    my_bit_list.append(num_of_one_divided_by_eight)

cross_entropy_list = []
i = 0
while i < len(my_bit_list):
    cross = cross_entropy([my_bit_list[i]], [my_bit_list[i + 1]])
    cross_entropy_list.append(cross)
    i = i + 2

df = pd.DataFrame(cross_entropy_list)
df.to_csv(r'AIMchat2.csv', index=False, index_label=False, chunksize=1000000, header=False)
```

I have changed `create_pickle_file()` to the code below to read files in the directory:

```
class PickleToFile:
    def __init__(self, name, pickle_file):
    self.name = name
    self.pickle_file = pickle_file

    def create_pickle_file(self):
    basepath = Path()
    files_in_basepath = basepath.iterdir('pickle/')
    for item in files_in_basepath:
        if item.is_file():
            checkThePickle = open(self.pickle_file, "rb")
            with open(self.name, 'w') as filehandler:
                for listItem in checkThePickle:
                    filehandler.write('%s\n' % listItem)
```

But since after reading file it writes it to a text file and then a csv file, I don't know how to do that. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to change the name of 'pickleData.txt'?  Using the 'input' statement will allow you to specify a file on the command line.  Or, if you'd like, you can use that input string, and modify it to create a new output file name; i.e. if input_file="file1.txt", you could create output_file = input_file + "_output.txt" , etc.  There are slicker ways of doing this, but is that what you need?

Comment: @asylumax The `pickleData.txt` is kinda working as an input file, because all the data would be read from it during the process, but I don't need it at the end, I just need the csv files. So I want to automate the process of reading `pickle` files and producing csv files.

Comment: Still a bit confused on what you want.   Do you want to eliminate an intermediary .txt file?  Can you update the question to show your process flow?

Comment: @asylumax Sure, I will put the whole code now. I don't want to eliminate that txt file, it is the file that used for all the process I've explained in the question.

Comment: @asylumax okay so the code is updated, all I want to do is to automate the process of reading pickle files and producing csv files, my code works on a single pickle file.

Comment: Sketch of a solution: put all pickle files in a single directory.  Have python open that directory, and get a list of all of those files.  Have a function that processes a pickle file, and then loop over that list of files with that function.

Comment: Yea, I would have done that, if I knew how to code it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get a list of files in directory and process them, this should get you what you want:

[How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory#3207973)

Once you have this list of files, do a loop:

```py
for each in list_of_files:
    process_function(each)
```

Then, you are on your way, where 'process_function' is the function, and the argument is the filename.